# Access 2003 query enhancement

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

table players:

```
name    play    Date1   Time1   
----    ----    -----   -----   
name1   play1   mydate1 mytime1 
name1   play1   mydate1 mytime2 
name1   play2   mydate2 mytime3
name2   play2   mydate1 mytime4 
name2   play3   mydate1 mytime5 
name2   play3   mydate3 mytime6
name3   play3   mydate1 mytime7 
name4   play4   mydate1 mytime8
```

without using min,max, distinct, group by, I am looking to get something like:

```
name    play    Date1+Time1
----    ----    -----------------------------
name1   xxxxx   hightest date+time when name1   
name2   xxxxx   hightest date+time when name2   
name3   xxxxx   hightest date+time when name3   
name4   xxxxx   hightest date+time when name4
```

play column should be the row with the highest date+time per a name.

I used the following query:

```
SELECT a.name, a.play, cdate(a.Date1+a.Time1)
FROM players AS a INNER JOIN players AS b ON (a.name=b.name) AND (cdate(a.Date1+a.Time1)>cdate(b.Date1+b.Time1))
WHERE (a.Date1>=date()-29);
```

I get something multiple same lines.

when i use max and group by, the query becomes read only which is not desired.

the correct outcome could look like this:

```
name    play    Date1+Time1
----    ----    ------------
name1   play2   date2+time3
name2   play3   date3+time6
name3   play3   date1+time7  
name4   play4   date1+time8
```

Comment: what are you expecting in the play column? How do you expect to make this updatable when combining lines?

Comment: whatever the play field is at the highest date+time row.

Comment: i tried different ways still does not give me the right output.

Comment: Do you have a PK? You could move the `MAX` into a subquery and have `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)`. If you have no PK you could try it with `EXISTS`. Not sure if it's updatable then, but worth a try.